# Additional search terms in JQuery Autocomplete 1.8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm a newbie with Jquery, so I may be missing something obvious... .

I am using JQuery's 1.8 autocomplete widget for a search search.  After the user enters 3 characters the function is triggered.  So "term" in the below function represents the characters in the street name.

However, the user will have already input their zip code and house number, and I would like those values to be passed to the query as well. How to I send those values, too?  I can only figure out how to send the single "term".

*(If it matters, I'm using ASP.Net MVC3)*

```
  $("#SearchStreet").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/VoterAndPollingPlaceLookup/PollingPlaceSearch/FindStreet",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 0
    });
```

EDIT: after help, the below is my new code that works just fine!

I have made the following updates:
My controller action that is being called:

```
Public Function FindStreet(term As String, searchZip As String, searchHouse As String) As JsonResult
           .....returns results
        End Function
```

Below is the updated Jquery.

```
 $("#SearchStreet").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/OnlineVoterRegistration/ApplicationDetails/FindStreet",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term, 
                        searchZip: $("#SearchZip").val(), 
                        searchHouse: $("#SearchHouse").val() }
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 0
    });
```

Comment: Are searchZip and searchHouse HTML inputs or .net controls?

Comment: they are the IDs of the HTML input fields.

Comment: I found the problem.  Capitalization.  (sheepish look on my face, now.  :-)  )  Turns out it should be "SearchZip" not "searchZip".  I'm going to edit my question to show the fixed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` parameter for the ajax request accepts a JSON object so all you have to do is add the other properties to that object. Like this:

```
$("#SearchStreet").autocomplete({ 
        source: function (request, response) { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "/VoterAndPollingPlaceLookup/PollingPlaceSearch/FindStreet", 
                dataType: "json", 
                data: { 
                    term: request.term,
                    zipCode: 'zip code',
                    houseNumber: 'house number'
                }, 
                success: function (data) { 
                    response($.map(data, function (item) { 
                        return { 
                            value: item 
                        } 
                    })); 
                } 
            }); 
        }, 
        minLength: 3, 
        delay: 0 
    });
```

In your controller action you have to add the parameters `zipCode` and `houseNumber`.

Comment: having trouble with this.  How do I get the values of the zip code and the house number from the request object?  I've tried a variety of ways - most recent is this:  data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    searchZip: $("#searchZip").val(),
                    searchHouse: $("#searchHouse").val()
                },

Comment: if you add the two mentioned parameters to the controller action you will be receiving them from the request. asp.net mvc knows how to map the JSON object properties to action parameters. in other words, your controller action signature should be looking like this: `public ActionResult FindStreet(string term, string zipCode, string houseNumber)`

Comment: I did that - I'll post a sample to my note above as additional info.